# Boilderplate-less Way to Upcast Scala Type Parameter to More General Trait

Tags: scala, types

I have a scenario that looks like this:

```scala
trait T { }
class A extends T { }

class Container[T](val value: T) { } 

val valueFromElsewhere = new Container[A](new A())
val container: Container[T] = valueFromElsewhere

implicit def boilderplate(a: Container[A]): Container[T] = new Container[T](a.value)
```

I want to use `valueFromElsewhere`. It is in a container, and the type parameter `A` of the container has trait `T` by specifications. I only need to use things from `T`.

But without `boilerplate`, the compiler doesn't know how to convert a `Container[A]` to a `Container[T]`. As there are many more classes other than `A` that have trait `T`, I'll need to write one implicit conversion for each of them. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: All you need is co-variance: `class Container[+W](val value: W) { }`

Comment: Without covariance (which is indeed the better solution) you still don't need to write a separate conversion for each subtype of `T`: `implicit def boilerplate(a: Container[_ <: T]): Container[T] = new Container[T](a.value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Suggested by @jwvh and @Alexey Romanov you can use these two solutions.

**From jwvh**

```
trait T
class A extends T

class Container[+W](val value: W)

val valueFromElsewhere = new Container[A](new A())
val container: Container[T] = valueFromElsewhere
//container: Container[T] = Container@69ba0e9
```

**From Alexey**

```
trait T {}

case class A(a: Int) extends T {}

case class B(b: Int) extends T {}

class Container[T](val value: T) {}


object application extends App {
  implicit def boilderplate(a: Container[_ <: T]): Container[T] = new Container[T](a.value)

  val valueFromElsewhere = new Container[A](A(1))
  val valueFromElseWhere2 = new Container[B](B(2))
  val container: Container[T] = valueFromElsewhere
  val container1: Container[T] = valueFromElseWhere2
}

 println(container.value)
 println(container1.value)
```